# Proper way to Dispose objects in C# WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms, dispose, idisposable

In a form that has a couple of DataGridViews I have two DataTables that are changed and accessed in various places throughout the form. I'm instantiating them like this:

```
public partial class frmXRefTool : Form
{
    private DataTable dtXref;
    private DataTable dtDefaults;
```

Both variable names have green squigglys under them with the message

> 'frmXrefTool' contains 'dtXref' that is of IDisposable type 'DataTable', but it is never disposed. Change the Dispose method on frmXrefTool to call Close or Dispose on this field.

In other cases, `using` will dispose the object, but how do I do that in this case?

Similarly, in Program.cs, this line has a green squiggly under `frmXrefTool()`:

```
Application.Run(new frmXRefTool());
```

With the message

> Call System.IDisposable.Dispose on object created by 'new frmXrefTool()' before all references to it are out of scope

How do properly handle that?

Comment: I don't get those messages.  Do you have an add-in that is creating those messages?

Comment: That last message you posted seems to offer the solution. Make your class IDisposable, then dispose your `new frmXRefTool()`.

Comment: I suppose there are other implications here, if there are other disposable objects..but you [don't need to dispose DataTables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62344806/proper-way-to-dispose-objects-in-c-sharp-winform). Although I suppose if you have some extension giving you warnings, that's probably just annoying, if anything.

Comment: That's just a warning to inform you proper lifecycle management should be applied on the objects. In simple cases, you can dispose them in `FormClosed` event, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.formclosed?view=netcore-3.1 But in complex cases you need more tracking.